# How to setup bind on osx Mavericks

Tags: bind, osx-mavericks

As stated in this question  I used brew install bind and sucessfully installend Bind on MacOs 10.9

[OSX Mavericks - BIND no longer installed... how to get local DNS server working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538118/osx-mavericks-bind-no-longer-installed-how-to-get-local-dns-server-working)

Please help me how to configure it to set named und rncd up and running. I find 
only tutorials for older versions for MacOs where bind was installed by default. But the old tutorials dont work anymore for generation rndc.conf file and to lauch the service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by completing what Homebrew should have done, but for some reason is not.

Homebrew is not creating the symlinks needed for BIND related executables.  Typically this happens automatically as part of the installation process.

If you navigate to your homebrew "Cellar", find the bind installation and the **sbin** directory within it, you will find all the named executables needed... for example, my sbin directory for bind is located at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/bind/9.9.3-P2/sbin
```

So the goal would be getting these files on the executable path.  The method is up to you.

You can do as Homebrew *should* and create a symlink for each of the files found in bind/*/sbin.  These symlinks are created in /usr/local/bin.

for example:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bind/9.9.3-P2/sbin/named /usr/local/bin/named
```

The other option is to put the homebrew bind path on your executable path by adding it to your .bashrc, .zshrc, .profile or whatever you use.

Personally I opted for following the convention homebrew uses and created individual links in my **/usr/local/bin** directory.

Once you have gone through all of this you should be able to configure things using **rndc-confgen**, etc. as directed by a number of tutorials.

Comment: I've updated the brew file to generate initial config files (to match the system install in Mountain Lion) as well as include a launchd plist. Though it's not merged in yet, you can see the updated file here: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/23598

Use `brew edit bind` to open the formula for BIND, and copy in my forked version, and reinstall with brew.

Comment: The pull request has been merged by now.