# osx Mavericks: dnsmasq stops working

Tags: macos, dns, osx-mavericks

I have been using dnsmasq on mac osx mountain lion which was installed via mac ports. Recently,I upgraded to Osx Mavericks and all of a sudden it has stopped working.

I examined the dnsmasq.conf and resolv.conf in /opt/local/etc/ which are unchanged. In addition the dnsmasq process is displayed running in the os activity monitor. I tried a force quit of the dnsmasq process as well.

Any suggestions? Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 21):

Solved mine by doing the following:

1. mkdir -pv $(brew --prefix)/etc/
2. echo 'address=/**.dev**/127.0.0.1' > $(brew --prefix)/etc/dnsmasq.conf
3. sudo cp -v $(brew --prefix dnsmasq)/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
4. sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
5. sudo mkdir -v /etc/resolver
6. sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolver/**dev**'

If your development domains are not **.dev**, then change the bolded parts to your domain. If you need other domains, you need to only repeat steps 2 and 6.

---

Source: [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20160318194450/http://echo.co/blog/never-touch-your-local-etchosts-file-os-x-again) brilliant blog post by Alan Ivey.

Comment: This worked for me. Although I had seen Alan Ivey's post, and my config was completely the same at first sight, I took these steps and after a restart everything works as expected.

Comment: Brava. This helps me a lot. It turns out to be that we need to do these 2 steps for maverick:
sudo mkdir -v /etc/resolver
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolver/dev'

Comment: Thanks.  This helped me too.  Was working previously, but just stopped, so the last 2 steps fixed my problem.

Comment: I'm on Yosemite and it stopped working for me. I did all steps and it still doesn't work. Please help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091959/dnsmasq-stopped-working-for-no-reason

Comment: Here's what was keeping me from getting the above to work.. if you're not running dnsmasq as root/admin (which we all really should be doing), you're going to have to get dnsmasq to listen on a different port than the default 53.  add 'port=35353' to dnsmasq.conf and 'port 35353' to /etc/resolver/dev

Answer (score 1):

The reason for why dnsmasq local-only domain not works any more on maverick is because BIND is no longer installed - even when the command line developer tools are added.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538118/osx-mavericks-bind-no-longer-installed-how-to-get-local-dns-server-working) is link for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with DNS after upgrade, in which is just wouldn't start from UI. Not using DNSMASQ myself, though you could look at this to see if is connected to your problem.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23469825#23469825

Edit (as root) plist at /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist

Look for `<key>org.isc.named</key>`

Set value of `<key>Disabled</key>` to `<false/>`.

Comment: I opened that file as root and found the following:
   <dict>
                <key>Disabled</key>
                <false/>
   </dict> , Still no luck